# How to call C# DLL function from VBScript

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript, function-calls

I have my script on server, so I do not have UI interaction available and have to use DLL instead of console application.

How to call a function in C# DLL from VBScript?

How do I make my DLL to be `COMVisible`? Do I have to register it?

Comment: Does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004352/call-a-function-in-a-console-app-from-vbscript

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to mark your assembly as COM visible by setting the [COMVisibleAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) to true (either at assembly level or at class level if you want to expose only a single type).

Next you register it with:

```
regasm /codebase MyAssembly.dll
```

and finally call it from VBScript:

```
dim myObj
Set myObj = CreateObject("MyNamespace.MyObject")
```

Comment: See also [Exposing .NET Components to COM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM?fid=14076&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=26#csharp)

Comment: Is it possible to use `Dim myObj As MyNamespace.MyObject` in VBScript as you can in VBA so you don't need `CreateObject`?  Is there an explicit reference you can make?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will need to set the `ComVisible` attribute to true and then register the assembly using regasm or regsvcs along with tlbexp. Then you can use `Server.CreateObject` and sail through.