# Cannot use CreateObject from VB scripts on Windows 7 x64

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

When I try to create a COM object in VB script on a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine, I always get the following error:

"ActiveX component can't create object 'xxx.xxx'.  Code: 800A01AD

I have applications that use the COM object without any problem.  I have tried running the command line in admin mode, no difference.

Is there any way to enable this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The VBScript interpreter (cscript.exe/wscript.exe) comes in two flavors on a 64-bit version of Windows: a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version.

The 32-bit version can create and use 32-bit COM components only, and the 64-bit version can create and use only 64-bit COM components.

By default, .vbs files are associated with the 64-bit version. You COM component is most likely a 32-bit one, hence the error.

You can find the 32-bit version in the `%windir%\SysWOW64` folder. Launching this version should give you access to all 32-bit COM components:

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\wscript.exe myScript.vbs
```

or

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe myScript.vbs
```

Comment: After banging my head for a couple of hours, you saved the day!

Comment: Do you know how to make this work for HTA applications, I'm seeing code like this: <script type="text/vbscript" src="utils.vbs"></script> and making it like this obviously fails: **<script type="text/vbscript" src="%windir%\SysWOW64\wscript.exe utils.vbs"></script>**

Comment: @JeremyThompson: You need to start the correct version of `mshta.exe`, i.e. the 32-bit version: `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe c:\page.hta`. If you want to enable starting the .hta by double-clicking in Explorer you probably could have your .hta restart with the correct version of mshta.exe.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I tried `SysWOW64\mshta.exe` initially and it didn't force the VBS files to run under 32 bit that's why I was trying to do it in the HTA file. I'll report back when I get this working.

Comment: %windir%\SysWoW64\wscript.exe in Browse I used the file path in add arguments and I set the program start in path but I could not able to get that done.The task seems to be successfully completed but there is no output as expected