# Use vb.net in VBScript

Tags: c#, .net, c++, vb.net, vbscript

How to call a function in vb.net DLL from VBScript?

I did the following: 
- I create public class named Class1 in vb.net.

- I go to Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt and go to my class dll - C:\Myapp\bin\Debug and type following command tlbexp myDLL.dll after that i get message Assembly exported to 
  C:\Myapp\bin\Debug\myDLL.tlb
- After this I type following command regasm myDLL.dll and i get following message 
  RegAsm  : warning  RA0000 : No types were registered

This is how my class look like:

```
Public Class Class1
   Public Function ADD(ByVal first As Integer, ByVal sec As Integer)
        Dim abc As Integer
        abc = first + sec
        Return abc
    End Function
    Public Function Subtraction(ByVal first As Integer, ByVal sec As Integer)
        Dim abc As Integer
        abc = first - sec
        Return abc
    End Function
end class
```

Where I am making mistake, and which is the easiest way to use vb.net from vbscript!

Many thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769332/how-to-call-c-dll-function-from-vbscript

Comment: When i try this regasm /codebase myDLL.dll i am getting The message:         "The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it. RegAsm : warning RA0000 : No types were registered"

Comment: Check out http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html. In particular the step **2. Configure project properties to make it COM visible**.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct path.  Does your class have a default contructor?  Does your class have a public method?

Also, right click on your project in Visual Studio.  I believe there is a "register for COM" or "make COM visible" checkbox to save you a few steps.

Comment: In your project properties, in the Compile section, you should check the "Register for COM interop" box.