# How do I determine the image dimensions of a tiff file?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, tiff

I have a vbscript script and I need to chew through a directory of .tif files.  For each file, I need to determine if the file is proportioned as a landscape or a portrait.  Basically, I need to be able to get the image dimensions for each file.  So for, I have seen some examples of people reading the file file headers to extract this sort of information from jpg or bmp files.  Has anyone done the same thing to extract the dimensions for a tiff file?

Comment: What else does your script need to do? If it's a standalone script, then you're far better off porting it to something else (.NET, Powershell) than trying to read TIFF files in VBScript. There used to be a free component called ImgSize.dll from ServerObjects that would do this, but it's been discontinued and is no longer available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In VBScript, you can determine the image dimensions in two ways:

1. Using the **WIA Automation Library** ([download link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29&displaylang=en), [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630827.aspx), [an excellent *Hey, Scripitng Guy!* article on the subject](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/11/16/how-can-i-determine-the-height-and-width-of-a-picture-file-without-using-windows-media-player.aspx)). Once you have the *wiaaut.dll* library registered, you can use the following simple code:

   ```
   Set oImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
   oImage.LoadFile "C:\Images\MyImage.tif"

   WScript.Echo "Width: "  & oImage.Width & vbNewLine & _
                "Height: " & oImage.Height
   ```
2. Using the [`GetDetailsOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787870.aspx) method to read the corresponding extended file properties. This is a native Windows scripting method, so no external libraries are required; but the code is longer:

   ```
   Const DIMENSIONS = 31
   CONST WIDTH  = 162
   CONST HEIGTH = 164

   Set oShell  = CreateObject ("Shell.Application")
   Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace ("C:\Images")
   Set oFile   = oFolder.ParseName("MyImage.tif")

   strDimensions = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFile, DIMENSIONS)    
   strWidth  = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFile, WIDTH)
   strHeigth = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFile, HEIGTH)

   WScript.Echo "Dimensions: " & strDimensions & vbNewLine & _
                "Width: "      & strWidth      & vbNewLine & _
                "Height: "     & strHeigth
   ```

   This script outputs something like:

   > Dimensions: 2464 x 3248
   >   Width: 2464 pixels
   >   Height: 3248 pixels

   so if you need plain numbers, you'll have to extract them from the returned strings.

   There's also another problem with this method - the property indexes (those constants in the beginning on the script) are different in different Windows versions, as I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674134/detecting-the-version-and-company-name-of-an-exe-using-jscript/2067780#2067780). The above script is for Windows 7, but if you use another Windows versions or if you want the script to work on different Windows versions, you'll need to use version-specific indexes. The most complete list of available property indexes is [here](http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=160880).

Comment: The Shell method was just what I was looking for.  Thanks Helen!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! (by the way, I already had wiaaut.dll present on my Vista and Win7 machines, so the script just worked straight away).

Comment: The property indexes also appear to be different for different image file types >_<

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Atalasoft's DotImage Photo](http://www.atalasoft.com/free-dotnet-image-sdk) Its powerful & it's free! But, it's a .NET package, so you'll have do some [Regasm Magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769332/how-to-call-c-dll-function-from-vbscript) to make it work. Go check out [Use vb.net in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176168/use-vb-net-in-vbscript) before you get started.

Here is the code you'll need to get the dimensions.

```
Public Function GetHeight(path As String) As Integer

    Using stm As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
        Dim decoder As New TiffDecoder()
        If Not decoder.IsValidFormat(stm) Then
            Throw New Exception("not a TIFF")
        End If
        Dim image As AtalaImage = decoder.Read(stm, Nothing)
        Return image.Height
            ' Return image.Width --- To return the Width.

    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: You are better off doing Dim info as ImageInfo = decoder.GetImageInfo(stm, Nothing) as this will allocate far less memory.  Also be aware that TIFF is a multi page format and dotImage PhotoFree doesn't support multipage documents, but dotImage PhotoPro and dotImage document imaging do.