# How to use regsam.exe for an Azure Website?

Tags: c#, azure, asp-classic

I have a classic asp site running on a Azure Websites Basic instance. I need to be able to execute code from in a C# assembly in my classic asp site.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769346/5651), I need to

1. Mark my C# assembly as COM visible (done)
2. Register the assembly with regsam.exe

How can I run regsam.exe for an Azure Website?  Is there any other way I can accomplish what I am after without using regsam?

Comment: i don't think you can do that since you are on a shared environment.

Comment: Daniel is right.  I tried running regasm.exe in the console in the new portal with a simple COM visible DLL and it failed returning error RA0000.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: As a workaround maybe you could wrap the DLL in a web API.