# VBScript to C# Communication

Tags: c#, winforms, vbscript

I am trying to create a vbscript that will call a C# form, and then return back to the script. The idea is to use C# as my form creator for my vbscript.

This is how I want the flow to work:

[image]

The func1, func2, and func3 will run depending on the input from the C# form.

I am not sure the best way to do this. I was hoping there was a way to make the form a DLL and have a return parameter.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Why not just use c# entirely?

Comment: What you're trying to do is called interoperability, i.e. the ability for "managed" code (.NET) and "unmanaged" code, -- COM (vbscript) to communicate.  It's too big a thing to talk about here on SO.  I would suggest you go seek information about it elsewhere.

Comment: Have a look at this question: [How to call C# DLL function from VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769332/how-to-call-c-sharp-dll-function-from-vbscript?rq=1). Add check all the **Related** links provided on the right-hand side of this page.

Comment: I did eventually find a question/answer similar to that one. However, I found a way around it by using the Shell() and waiting for a return value from main.